# How to mock objects of external libraries?

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I have the following method that I want to test:

```java
    public String createUser(Keycloak keycloak) {
        final Response response = keycloak.realm(this.realm).users().create(this.toUserRepresentation());
        String userId = response.getLocation().getPath().replaceAll(".*/([^/]+)$", "$1");
        return userId;
    }
```

I have tried with this but the getPath() always return an empty string.

```java
@PrepareForTest(URI.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
class UserTest {

    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    private Keycloak keycloak;

    @Mock
    private Response response;

    @Test
    public void createUserTest() throws Exception {
        URI uri = PowerMockito.mock(URI.class);

        when(uri.getPath()).thenReturn("https://myserver/myid[\r][\n]");
        when(response.getLocation()).thenReturn(uri);
        when(keycloak.realm(any()).users().create(any())).thenReturn(response);


        assertEquals("myid", user.createUser(keycloak));
    }

}
```

How should I mock the URI.getPath() called so that it returns the expected value?

Comment: If you're using `Mockito.when`, try switching to `PowerMockito.when`

Comment: As an aside: is there any reason you cannot just create a concrete URI instance, since the thing you're actually mocking is the `Response`?  You wouldn't have to use PowerMock then.

Comment: @rdas If I use `PowerMockito.when` I get the following Exception: `java.lang.Exception: Test class should have public zero-argument constructor`

Comment: @stridecolossus Yes, that's an alternative that would work but I want to avoid it for the general case. In this case the object is simple and easy to create, but what if the object is too complex and have a long list dependencies of dependencies? Isn't it possible to mock that object to avoid writing all the boilerplate?

Comment: @gonditeniz Yes. That's the whole point of mocking, you create mocks for the dependencies of the class under test and any collaborators (`Response` and `keycloak` in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to include the class under test in the @PrepareForTest annotation. For example:

```
@PrepareForTest({URI.class, User.class})
```

Then uri.getPath() will return a non-empty value.

---

Please notice that you test URI will never evaluate to just "myid", it will also include "[\r][\n]".

```
("https://myserver/myid[\r][\n]").replaceAll(".*/([^/]+)$", "$1")
```

Comment: This worked for me, although I think the URI.class is not needed. My error was primarily using URI.class instead of User.class.